# Click on linkbutton in control in Repeater captures wrong event handler

Tags: asp.net

I have a UserControl that contains a LinkButton with a OnClick. The UserControl I inserted in Repeater with OnItemCommand  in separate UserControl.

The problem is that click on LinkButton ever capture Repeater OnItemCommand and not LinkButoon OnClick.

The simplified code:

MyControl.ascx

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="lbtGeneratePDF_Click" Text="Generate pdf" />
...
```

OtherControl.ascx

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="grvOffers_Command" ID="grvOffers">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <c:MyControl runat="server" />
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

OtherControl.ascx.cs

```
grvOffers.DataSource = GetOffers(); // Type is List<Offer>
grvOffers.DataBind();
```

I use .net version 3.5

Comment: Could you post your repeater binding code, along with the page event that performs this binding?

Answer (score 0):

Why is that a problem? That's just the way repeater works :) Just add a command name to the LinkButton, instead of using OnClick, and then call your lbtGeneratePDF_Click from OnItemCommand when CommandName is equal to your button's command name. You can also use CommandArgument to pass any other information, such as a row id or whatever you need.

Or use the OnCommand event on the LinkButton, rather than OnClick.

To clarify a bit more, you can't have a postback on a server control inside a Repeater (the control is created a bit more dynamically than usual, and is data bound in runtime), which is why the Command infrastructure exists in the firstplace - the OnCommand postback event is propagated to the correct control. OnClick is never raised in the first place.

Comment: If the LinkButton in the Repeater is correct to call OnItemCommand. LinkButton but in a **separate UserControl** so it is nonsense to another UserControl called the operator. In addition, sometimes starts and sometimes legally OnClick OnItemCommand.

Comment: @MurdejUkrutný: Your sample code doesn't show any server control IDs. Is it possible that the actual ID of your LinkButton is the same as some control in the Repeater? Or the repeater itself? Just look at the generated HTML.

Comment: @MurdejUkrutný: Oh, now I see that you're actually using MyControl inside the repeater. My answer still stands, though. The post back is still handled by the Repeater, rather than MyControl, so it still does OnItemCommand, rather than your OnClick. MyControl has to implement INamingContainer and it has to have an ID (and the LinkButton has to have an ID too).